# Can't convert JSON to Python List

Tags: python, json, google-analytics

I am creating a dashboard for Google Analytics and I want to convert the JSON what is coming from Google Analytics into a python list, but keep getting this error:

```
Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Here is the code which should convert it:

```
results = get_results(service, profile)
data = json.loads(str(results))
return data
```

Results is equal to:

```
{u'columnHeaders': [{u'columnType': u'METRIC',
                 u'dataType': u'INTEGER',
                 u'name': u'ga:sessions'}],
u'containsSampledData': False,
u'id': u'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:xxxxxxxx&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today',
u'itemsPerPage': 1000,
u'kind': u'analytics#gaData',
u'profileInfo': {u'accountId': u'xxxxxxxx',
              u'internalWebPropertyId': u'xxxxxxxx',
              u'profileId': u'xxxxxxxx',
              u'profileName': u'xxxxxxxx',
              u'tableId': u'ga:xxxxxxxx',
              u'webPropertyId': u'UA-xxxxxxxx-1'},
u'query': {u'end-date': u'today',
        u'ids': u'ga:xxxxxxxx',
        u'max-results': 1000,
        u'metrics': [u'ga:sessions'],
        u'start-date': u'7daysAgo',
        u'start-index': 1},
u'rows': [[u'109826']],
u'selfLink': u'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:76270671&metrics=ga:sessions&start-date=7daysAgo&end-date=today',
u'totalResults': 1,
u'totalsForAllResults': {u'ga:sessions': u'109826'}}
```

I have removed some account details above but hopefully get the picture.

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: this is not JSON, `results` might already be a dict

Comment: What is type of `results` (do `print(type(results))`)?

Comment: What should the list look like? As is clear in your results dict, it is a tree structure, which is generally the case for JSON data.

Comment: I'm new to Python, and I think I have been getting them mixed up, thanks for all your help!

Comment: json.loads() returns a python dictionary of the data you retrieved in json format. It isn't a list.  Please post your complete traceback and your actual code

Answer (score 2):

your result doesnt look like a string much more like a python object (dict)
(because of the unicode mark before every string)
maybe your should try this:

```
print(type(result))
```